# Salesforce cURL Example with Session ID is not working

Tags: rest-api, rest, saml

I'm trying to use the Salesforce Rest API with the session ID I received via a SAML Response from the same Salesforce Instance (as IDP) but I get the message:

> [{"message":"This session is not valid for use with the REST
>   API","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]

Is there a restriction on Session IDs received via SAML Response? I was following this intro: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_curl.htm but i'm not able to call a custom webservice.

- Is this even possible with a Session ID received via SAML Response?
- Is there any other way of using Rest API with Session ID from SAML?

Comment: When you say SAML Response, are you talking about the actual SAML response from your IdP?

Comment: Exactly. We use SF as the identity Provider and include  the Session id as custom Attribute in the response. We would now want to use this session id to call the rest API of the same Salesforce org.

Comment: Ah OK, so just to recap, Salesforce is you IdP and you are sending the Session Id / Access token, to your SP Application as a custom attribute correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Comment: And I am guessing you are implementing `Auth.ConnectedAppPlugin` and adding a the attribute `UserInfo.getSessionId()` in the `global override Map<String,String> customAttributes` method

Comment: No I'm using the custom Attribute $api.sessionid from the connected app configuration page for this. But we are also using the Auth.ConnectedAppPugin for other custom attributes. Is there a difference if you implement it from the configuration settings or in the ConnectedAppPlugin?

Answer (score 0):

So I just tried exactly what you said and it worked. I added the custom attribute `$Api.Session_ID` and then I performed this callout in POSTMAN:

```
GET /services/data HTTP/1.1
Host: {myidp}-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com
Authorization: Bearer 00Df{redacted}GdahsD37VNi2Pg6wNIb7SeCUzyrmD.
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.19.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Host: {myIdP}-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
cache-control: no-cache
```

Would you be able to share a semi-redacted version of your sessionId so we can see if it is close to the expected format

Comment: Hm but that shows it's working... Must be some misconfiguration on my end. Now I only have to figure out what it is :) thanks a lot for your support.